# Weird behavior in IE when running if on date.toLocaleString day of week

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I've been struggling with this for hours, all I need is to check if the date is Tuesday. My code works perfectly in Chrome, Firefox, etc but it just won't work in IE.

```
<script>
var date = new Date('2020-07-21');
var dayOfWeek = String(date.toLocaleString('en-us', {  weekday: 'short' }));
        
if ( dayOfWeek == "Tue" ) {
    console.log("Works");
} else {
    console.log("Doesn't work");
}
</script>
```

The log in this case, on **IE** is: **Doesn't work**

The log in this case, on **Chrome** is: **Works**

The value of ***dayOfWeek*** in this case is ***Tue***. But when I try to run an If on the variable in IE, it doesn't match. I've tried multiple iterations of String casting and if I explicitly set the value of ***dayOfWeek*** to ***Tue*** it works. But not if I get the day of week string from the **date.toLocalString** function. Can someone tell me why it's doing this?

**Edit:** Forgot to mention, if I call **console.log(dayOfWeek)** in IE, it logs: **Tue**. That's where my confusion stems from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experimentation, I found that `String(date.toLocaleString('en-us', {  weekday: 'short' }));` returns a string of length 4 which are `'', 'T', 'u', 'e'`, which I found is a known bug, so if you can take the substring of the last 3 letters, it should work.

I did that using slice but you can use whatever is more suitable but keep in mind it should be cross-browser compatible.

`dayOfWeek = dayOfWeek.slice(dayOfWeek.length - 3)`